# Ordering a Set within a domain object

Tags: hibernate, jpa, set

I am using Hibernate and JPA. I currently have reverse engineered DAO which gives me a list of all 50 States.

Within each state is a list of items.  `Set<Items>`

The Items class has a property called `name`.

I need to return a `list of States` - Doesn't matter the order. But each item within the state needs to be returned in alphabetical order?

Here is the DAO.

```
public List<State> findAll() {
        EntityManagerHelper
                .log("finding all State instances", Level.INFO, null);
        try {
            final String queryString = "select model from State model";
            Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
            return query.getResultList();
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            EntityManagerHelper.log("find all failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

And here is the State

```
public class State implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Set<Item> items= new HashSet<Item>(0);
}
```

And this needs to be ordered by a property in the Item called Name.

Comment: Hashset is not ordered. At. All. Use a List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the JPA annotation **[javax.persistence.OrderBy](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html)**.

For example :

```
public class State {
    private Set<Item> items= new HashSet<Item>(0);

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "state")
    @OrderBy("name")
    public Set<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    // Setter
}
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that HashSet will not preserve any ordering (see the javadoc for HashSet), so such an action would be futile.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is unordered.  There are implementations that will give a determinate iteration order like [LinkedHashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), but you should use a list if you want to maintain order.  Even if the values are returned to Java in an ordered format, the order will not be preserved when you put them into a vanilla HashSet.

If you don't want to return the items in order, you should look into implementing the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface for your State object, or implementing a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that will look at the Name property of the State to evaluate order.